# How to display API calling went wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, error-handling, material-ui

I want to show an error message when calling api has problem and it position is under the material-ui TextField to say "Something went wrong! Reload?".
When user clicked "Reload?" call api again and show error until api absolutely call.
With this work TextField should check input is empty or not and check true values are received.

Like this picture:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tm_P38gXrZI4qzpTqRWVYYVCakDyQunQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.